# Some different questions about Coupon Collector Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, coupon-collector

1) after n days, what is expected value of number of first type coupons.

2) after n days, what is the expected value of number of types of coupons.

For the first one, I've considered decent and just did a random variable X that is an indicator for receving a first type coupon, and I just calculate E[$\Sigma$Xi] and get 1 and thats the expected value for the first question. (I think it is the answer).

Now the second questions is a bit tricky, could use some help to get me going.
Thanks!

Comment: For the second, let $Y_i$ be the indicator variable that tells you if you got coupon $i$ or not (at least once over the $n$ days).

Comment: Note:  you didn't describe the problem fully, so there's no way to check a numerical answer.  You didn't, say, specify that there are also $n$ available coupons.  If you did mean to assume that, then I agree with your answer (and your reasoning).

Comment: Thank you! I've calculated it and the answer is (1+n)/2, is it correct?

Comment: There are n Coupons

Comment: There are $n$ coupons in total?  If so, the probability that you never see the $i^{th}$ coupon is $\left( \frac {n-1}n \right)^n$ so $E[Y_i]=1-\left( \frac {n-1}n \right)^n$  Your answer is then $n\times E[Y_i]$.  Where did your expression come from?

Comment: Never mind, was a bit confused but now I understand. Thanks!

Comment: A suggestion: I think it's better not to restrict to "number of coupons = number of days".  Makes it hard to check asymptotic properties.  Let's say there are $n$ coupons and $d$ days.  My calculation says that the expected number of coupons you see is $n\times \left(1-\left( \frac {n-1}n \right)^d\right)$.  Note that this goes to $n$ as $d \to \infty$ as it should.